# Return Custom Json Result in WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

In Wcf Rest serivce how to return custom Json? 
Like: if i have a Json result for a model

```
{'name':'R2D2', 'location':'starship'}
```

I want to have a custom Json Result like

```
{'Status':'OK', 'data':{'name':'R2D2', 'location':'starship'}, 'Message':'',...
}
```

How can i achieve this function?

I did some how achieve it... Not sure if it is the best way.

```
 public class JsonResult<T>
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
```

in Service

```
 [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        JsonResult<Robot> TestJson();
```

It does Give me my desired Result. 
Is this the best way? or There are other methods Too?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control your response format you can implement a custom IDispatchMessageFormatter (a custom WebMessageFormat).

There is a nice post in here: http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/wcf-rest-custom-webmessageformat.html